# SignalR 3.0.0 won't generate the Javascript hub proxy

Tags: signalr

I'm using a new build of 3.0, which is not RTM (December 2015), with the RC1 bits of the rest of ASP.NET 5. I have the .AddSignalR() method in my start up, but I'm not getting the /signalr/js proxy. It comes up as 404. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `app.UseSignalR()` also in your `Startup.Configure()`.

Comment: Ugh... that's too obvious. Kind of weird to have two different places to wire it up in startup, even though I do understand why.